# Get Product id from order_item_info array

Tags: magento

When I print array of  order_item_info using

> echo "
>
> ```
> "; print_r($profile['order_item_info']); echo"
> ```
>
> ";

It Prints array like This

a:74:{s:7:"item_id";s:3:"108";s:8:"quote_id";s:2:"92";s:10:"created_at";s:19:"2014-06-25 08:32:20";s:10:"updated_at";s:19:"2014-06-25 08:32:20";s:10:"product_id";s:1:"6";s:8:"store_id";s:1:"1";s:14:"parent_item_id";N;s:10:"is_virtual";s:1:"0";s:3:"sku";s:10:"one-yr-sub";s:4:"name";s:8:"One Year";s:11:"description";N;s:16:"applied_rule_ids";s:0:"";s:15:"additional_data";N;s:13:"free_shipping";s:1:"0";s:14:"is_qty_decimal";s:1:"0";s:11:"no_discount";s:1:"0";s:6:"weight";s:6:"0.0010";s:3:"qty";i:1;s:5:"price";d:100;s:10:"base_price";d:100;s:12:"custom_price";N;s:16:"discount_percent";i:0;s:15:"discount_amount";i:0;s:20:"base_discount_amount";i:0;s:11:"tax_percent";i:0;s:10:"tax_amount";i:0;s:15:"base_tax_amount";i:0;s:9:"row_total";d:100;s:14:"base_row_total";d:100;s:23:"row_total_with_discount";s:6:"0.0000";s:10:"row_weight";d:0.001000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375;s:12:"product_type";s:6:"simple";s:24:"base_tax_before_discount";N;s:19:"tax_before_discount";N;s:21:"original_custom_price";N;s:12:"redirect_url";N;s:9:"base_cost";N;s:14:"price_incl_tax";d:100;s:19:"base_price_incl_tax";d:100;s:18:"row_total_incl_tax";d:100;s:23:"base_row_total_incl_tax";d:100;s:17:"hidden_tax_amount";i:0;s:22:"base_hidden_tax_amount";i:0;s:15:"gift_message_id";N;s:20:"weee_tax_disposition";i:0;s:24:"weee_tax_row_disposition";i:0;s:25:"base_weee_tax_disposition";i:0;s:29:"base_weee_tax_row_disposition";i:0;s:16:"weee_tax_applied";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:23:"weee_tax_applied_amount";i:0;s:27:"weee_tax_applied_row_amount";i:0;s:28:"base_weee_tax_applied_amount";i:0;s:30:"base_weee_tax_applied_row_amnt";N;s:11:"qty_options";a:0:{}s:12:"tax_class_id";s:1:"0";s:12:"is_recurring";s:1:"1";s:9:"has_error";b:0;s:10:"is_nominal";b:1;s:22:"base_calculation_price";d:100;s:17:"calculation_price";d:100;s:15:"converted_price";d:100;s:19:"base_original_price";d:100;s:14:"taxable_amount";d:100;s:19:"base_taxable_amount";d:100;s:17:"is_price_incl_tax";b:0;s:14:"original_price";d:100;s:32:"base_weee_tax_applied_row_amount";i:0;s:25:"discount_tax_compensation";i:0;s:20:"base_shipping_amount";d:5;s:15:"shipping_amount";d:5;s:17:"nominal_row_total";d:105;s:22:"base_nominal_row_total";d:105;s:21:"nominal_total_details";a:0:{}s:15:"info_buyRequest";s:225:"a:4:{s:4:"uenc";s:124:"aHR0cDovL2J3Y211bHRpbWVkaWEuY29tL0UvZXh0ZW5zaW9udGVzdC9pbmRleC5waHAvbXVsdGl2ZW5kb3IvdmVuZG9ycHJvZHVjdHMvc3Vic2NyaXB0aW9uLw,,";s:7:"product";s:1:"6";s:8:"form_key";s:16:"be2eDRXu1MC7OXfK";s:3:"qty";i:1;}";}

This array contains product_id now i want to separate that product_id from that array . how can i do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That output is not really an array, but rather a serialized, string representation of an array and so you must unserialize it first. (http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.unserialize.php) - you can do that like so:

```
$order_item_info = unserialize($profile['order_item_info']);
```

Then you can access the array as normal for example:

```
print_r($order_item_info['product_id']);
```